# Ember.js - Function finished before store is done

Tags: ember.js

I'm building an ember app, and I keep running into the same problem where I make a call to the store, but the function keeps compiling before the store has retrieved the data from the backend. Specifically I'm having the problem with a findRecord. I've implemented it both ways:

```
var admin = this.store.findRecord('admin', 1);
console.log(admin.get('season'));
console.log('Are we here?');
```

and

```
this.store.findRecord('admin', 1).then(function(admin) {
  console.log(admin.get('season'));
});
console.log('Are we here?');
```

In both cases, the `Are we here?` is logged BEFORE the season. Obviously the console logs are just for the example, and it creates an actual problem with what I'm trying to get done. Does anybody know a simple fix for this delay?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Note that [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) duplicate applies even if you don't use return value - you still expect something to happen after return from asynchronous function.

Comment: Some of Ember Data's APIs are **synchronous**, meaning the return with the value immediately. For instance, `peekRecord`. `findRecord` is **asynchronous**, meaning it returns a promise, and any processing must be done within a `then` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. It's an asynchronous behavior. It takes some time to solve promise which is returned from `findRecord()`, thus the consequence is:

```
this.store.findRecord(); //synchronous
console.log('we are here'); //synchronous
```

in the meantime a promise returned from `findRecord()` gets resolved (asynchronous behavior)

```
console.log(admin.get('season'));
```

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous call will not stop your code from progressing, that´s the purpose of it. Else it would block UI updates and user interaction while loading data.